# MySQL output beginner level

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning MySQL and I have a doubt which I would like you to clarify. Here's the code:

```sql
select case
            when a+b>c and a+c>b and b+c>a then
                case
                    when a=b or b=c or a=c then 'Isosceles'
                    when a=b and b=c then 'Equilateral'
                    else 'Scalene'
                end
            else 'Not A Triangle'  
         end
from triangles;
```

If I swap the 4th and 5th lines the output also changes. I want to know why this happens. Is it the same thing if I write the 4th line before or the 5th line? Shouldn't the output be same?

Comment: `CASE` statements are handled in the order they’re written. The first `WHEN` that matches the criteria will always win. The `when a=b and b=c` line must come first, otherwise the `when a=b` before it will always usurp the condition 

Comment: Formaĺly you must also check that none variable is zero or negative...

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Choose your tags with care, know which database engine you are using, don't spam the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here I will try to explain it with two example of sample data.

Let's assume that there are two scenario

1. a=1, b=1, c=1. So, a=b  and b=c  and a=c
2. a=1, b=2, c=1. So, a<>b and b<>c and a=c

For both scenario first condition (a=b or b=c or a=c ) is true but the second condition (a=b and b=c) is only true for first scenario where a=b and b=c is true.

So, since first condition is true for both the scenario second condition will never be tried. As a result you will get 'Isosceles' for first and second scenario.

On the other hand if you write the second condition first and first condition second like below:

```
                case                        
                    when a=b and b=c then 'Equilateral'
                    when a=b or b=c or a=c then 'Isosceles'
                    else 'Scalene'
                end
```

First condition will be satisfied for first scenario and will be false for second scenario. But second condition will be true for second scenario where  a=c is true. As a result you will get 'Equilateral' for first scenario and 'Isosceles' for second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't.  **when a=b or b=c or a=c** tells than it matched **any** equality.
And **a=b and b=c** matches only when both equalities are met

Particularly in this case the 5th line wont be executed because 4th line will catch everything.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression evaluates the conditions in order.  Hence, the *first* condition that matches will be what is returned.

In your case, an equilateral triangle meets the condition `a=b or b=c or a=c` because it trivially meets `a=b`.  Hence, it is called `isosceles`.

One way to write the conditions -- assuming none of the values are `null` and all are positive -- is:

```
select (case when a = b and b = c and a = c
             then Equilateral
             when a + b <= c or a + c <= b or b + c <= a
             then 'Not A Triangle'
             when a = b or b = c or c = a
             then 'Isosceles'
             else 'Scalene'
         end)
from triangles;
```

Comment: This will return `'Equilateral'` for a=b=c=0. The first condition that should be checked is the triangular inequalities.

Comment: @forpas . . . The preceding paragraph says that all the values are **positive**.  `0` is not positive.

Comment: There is no mention in the question that all values are positive. Also the code in the question checks the condition: `a+b>c and a+c>b and b+c>a`. So your assumption is `false`.